# Static Allocation vs Dynamic Allocation [IP Addresses]

Tags: ip, dhcp

Quick question regarding static vs dynamic allocation of IP addresses.
I understand that in static IP addressing the address does not change while in dynamic addressing it could differ each time a new IP is leased. I also understand some theoretical concepts. However, I have a question regarding how static IP addresses are assigned: If we have a network, does the sysadmin/network engineer have to assign a static IP on *every* device on the network ? as in *physically go to the device and assign a static IP* OR is there a way to assign multiple static IP addresses (That do not change and remain constant for the entire time)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static IP addresses are configured locally on a host. A host can also have multiple IP addresses on an interface. How this is configured exactly depends on the host and is off-topic here.

If you want to use dynamic, centrally managed addresses but don't want them to change after lease expiration you should use DHCP with reserved addresses.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i needed to know :)